# Creating a new Phabricator task with javascript

Tags: javascript, phabricator

I am trying to connect to Phabricator conduit API and create a task via a javascript bonded to a google sheet.

The Conduit API Docs [linked here](https://secure.phabricator.com/conduit/method/maniphest.edit/) doesn't really explain as much. I have seen better API documentations!

Below is what I have in mind but this is a cURL and I have no idea how to make it Javascript or wither this would work or not? I appreciate the help

```
curl https://secure.phabricator.com/api/maniphest.edit \
-d api.token=api-token \
-d param= [
    {
      "type": "title",
      "value": "A value from a cell on the googlesheet"
    },
    {
      "type": "description",
      "value": "A value from a cell on the googlesheet"
    },
    {
      "type": "subscribers.add",
      "value": "A value from a cell on the googlesheet"
    }
  ] \
```

Comment: Did you figure this out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally speaking the steps are:

First, generate an API token in: 
https://phabricator.yourdomain.com/settings/user/username/page/apitokens/

where `phabricator.yourdomain.com` must be changed by the subdomain you have Phabricator installed and `username` must be changed by your administration user name.

Then, let's say you have installed Phabricator in `phabricator.yourdomain.com`, you can request the API methods with URLs of the following type

https://phabricator.yourdomain.com/api/method_name?parameter1=value1&parameter2=value2...

where `method_name` must be replaced by the descriptor of a real method from this catalog:
https://secure.phabricator.com/conduit/

For example, if you want to read the contents of task number `125`, with a generated API token of value `api-svhcp2a3qmgkkjfa5f6sh7cm4joz`, use the method `maniphest.info` to complete a URL like this:

```
http://phabricator.yourdomain.com/api/maniphest.info?api.token=api-svhcp2a3qmgkkjfa5f6sh7cm4joz&task_id=125&output=json
```

This URL can be directly tested in your preferred browser to obtain a JSON response with the information about task number 125 (make sure that task ID exists). Firefox will even show the returned JSON in a human-readable fashion.

These working URLs can be then inserted in Javascript as

```
window.location.href=http://phabricator.yourdomain.com/api/maniphest.info?api.token=api-svhcp2a3qmgkkjfa5f6sh7cm4joz&task_id=125&output=json
```

or as an asynchronous Ajax call.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem as you (I used HTTParty with Ruby).
To solve it I used the following body (using your example):

```
"transactions[0][type]=title&transactions[0][value][0]=A value from a cell on the googlesheet&transactions[1][type]=description&transactions[1][value]=A value from a cell on the googlesheet&transactions[2][type]=subscribers.add&transactions[2][value][0]=A value from a cell on the googlesheet"
```